# How do I get my rooted Incredible to install the latest Verizon update?

Tags: updates, htc-droid-incredible, verizon

Leaving aside the question of [whether the update is a good idea or not](http://www.electronista.com/articles/10/11/04/droid.incredible.to.get.mandatory.verizon.app.shop/) -- I'm tired of seeing "update available. Install?" show up every other day. I click "Yes", and it tells me rebooting in 10..9..8...1 ..... only it never reboots.

This [incredible forum post](http://www.incredibleforum.com/forum/htc-incredible-roms/6418-sr3-3-3-ota-updates.html) suggests that being rooted is why it won't install. But.... is there some way to force it anyway?

Or do I have to unroot, update, re-root?

Comment: Being rooted is not the cause; my Incredible is having the same problems and I'm not rom'd or rooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running the stock ROM, only rooted?  If so, you have a few options.

1. RUU to the latest OTA & reroot.  [Available Here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=829783)  (Requires Unrevoked 3.22)
2. Install a pre-rooted ROM.  [Available Here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=765930)

If you're running a different ROM, you should be able to do a build.prop edit to keep from seeing OTA notifications (and burning your battery, redownloading the OTA constantly, etc.).  [This post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9150733&postcount=5) describes what needs modified.

Finally, you can flash a ROM based on the latest OTA.

Comment: Yes, it's the stock ROM. I rooted so I could take screenshots, basically. And so I could say I rooted my phone. !!! Srsly, have to re-install the ROMs for all of this? Ouch.

Comment: Are you already running Froyo?  If so, grab the pre-rooted ROM, toss it on your SD card, reboot into recovery, wipe cache/Davlik cache (Davlik is under the advanced menu), then flash the new ROM.  No need to wipe data and have to go about reconfiguring everything.  This will probably take less time than unrooting, dealing with the OTA, then rerooting.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I had to boot into the recovery menu and clear the system install cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uninstalled any of the stock apps, including any of the bloatware, the OTA update will not work as it also updates those apps.  I know of quite a few people that have been bitten by this.

If you don't want certain stock apps running, you're better off freezing them with Titanium Backup than removing them.